# Is there a way to make this rock paper scissors more code-efficent ? (less lines, in a better way)

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to make the game better and more code-efficent? I'm new to python so this game works but I'm sure there's an easier way to do what I did

```
import random
Answers = [
    "rock",
    "paper",
    "scissors",
]
Answer = input("rock / paper / scissors ?\n")
RandomNum = random.choice(Answers)
print(RandomNum)
while Answer == RandomNum:
    print("Tie, try again")
    Answer = input("rock / paper / scissors ?\n")
    RandomNum = random.choice(Answers)
    print(RandomNum)
if (int(len(Answer)) - int(len(RandomNum))) == -4: #if User input is Rock - Scissors = -4
    print("You have won")
else:
    if (int(len(Answer)) - int(len(RandomNum))) == 4:  # if User input is Scissors - Rock = 4
        print("You have lost")
    else:
        if (int(len(Answer)) - int(len(RandomNum))) == -3:  # if User input is Paper - Scissors = -3
            print("You have lost")
        else:
            if (int(len(Answer)) - int(len(RandomNum))) == 3:  # if user input is Scissors - Paper = 3
                print("You have won")
            else:
                if int(len(Answer)) > int(len(RandomNum)):  # answers except scissors and paper
                    print("You have won")
                else:
                    print("You have lost")
```

it works fine but if the user enters invalid answer it will think its an actual answer so i don't know really how to fix that, and make the code better

Comment: I think you are over thinking it, you could just use rock paper scissors as themselves in an if, elif statement and if the user enters nothing you just do.    if Answer:. And then the last else: as your error

Comment: This question may be more on topic over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. StackOverflow is primarily for helping to fix or identify problems in broken code, rather than improve existing code

Comment: You may need variables for players

Comment: Calculating the difference of length between words is a very strange and not very robust way to compare them. Something like `if answer == 'Scissors' and random_num == 'Rock':` is clearer and easier to maintain. Also, note that the usage in Python is to use capitalized names only for class names. And have a look at `elif`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple approach is to maintain a dictionary of who beats whom, which will look like.
`{'rock':'scissors','scissors':'paper','paper':'rock'}` as rock beats scissors, scissors beats paper, and paper beats rock.

Then we can code our approach as follows.

```
import random

#dictionary of who beats whom
beats = {'rock':'scissors','scissors':'paper','paper':'rock'}

#All possible answers
answers = list(beats.keys())

#Take answer from user and chose comp answer at random
user_answer = input("rock / paper / scissors ?\n")
comp_answer = random.choice(answers)

print('I chose', comp_answer)

#Check if user input is valid
if user_answer not in beats.keys():
    print('Invalid input')

#If both comp and user choose same, they tie
elif user_answer == comp_answer:
    print('Tied, Try again')

#If user answer was in key, and comp_answer was in value, user wins
elif beats[user_answer] == comp_answer:
    print('You have won')

#Otherwise comp wins
else:
    print('You have lost')
```